# How to write a query to add a prefix to a comma separated string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

- I have a table in a MySQL database with a column `id`.
- The id column has comma separated values stored in it in VARCHAR format.
- I want to add a prefix `C` to every value in the output of the query.

Ex:

```
Current Query: select id from table; 
Current Output: 1,2,3,4

Desired Output: C1,C2,C3,C4
```

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Do you have a chance to fix this broken database design before you continue?

Comment: This is not my design actually. I am just bridging the gap in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all sounds like a bad idea, but in some situations it might be needed.

It seems that treating `id` as a string, and applying string functions to it, is the best solution. If you want to do this non-permanent, you can do it this way:

```
SELECT
  id AS oldId,
  IF(LENGTH(id) > 0, CONCAT('C', REPLACE(id, ',', ',C')), '') AS newId
FROM
  table;
```

This works by first checking if there's something in `id`. If there isn't, it is left empty. If there is content, a `C` is added at the front and after every comma.

if you want to make this permanent, you could do:

```
UPDATE
  table
SET
  id = IF(LENGTH(id) > 0, CONCAT('C', REPLACE(id, ',', ',C')), '');
```

This changes the content of your table. **Apply with care and only once.**

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked smoothly. Unfortunately, update is not an option. Just fetch and prepare the string.